# Starting Instagram Win10 store app

Tags: windows-10, instagram, sikuli-ide

I'm currently doing a small program with the SikuliX IDE that should mostly open the Instagram windows 10 store application if present.

I understand that windows store app are stored there:

```
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\
```

But I remarked that there is number string in the app directory

```
[...]736B6gK7_Instagram[...]
```

My question is, is this directory is always the same for each Instagram app installation/version? What's is representing exactly?

Also, is there an .exe for each app like :

```
[...]736B6gK7_Instagram[...]/instagram.exe
```

Comment: https://www.tenforums.com/software-apps/57000-method-open-any-windows-10-apps-command-line.html

Comment: thanks I'll try to automate this.